# Using a US state for payroll while not being a resident

Tags: united-states, taxes, state-income-tax, foreign-income, france

I'm an American currently living in France with my wife (also an American). She has a part-time job working remotely for an American company. This company uses a US-only payroll company, so my wife was forced to provide a US address. She gave the address of the last place we lived (in Pennsylvania), and that's been the address the payroll company has been using for the last year. The problem of course is that we no longer live at this address. We've lived in France long enough for it to become our tax base.

I have two questions concerning this situation. The first is whether we'll be able to recuperate the state and local taxes that we paid for 2019. The second is whether there is any problem with continuing like this going forward, given that her employer claims they need a US address to pay her.

Comment: what state is the company based in? That may be the state you want to use (does it have to be valid?) since that's where tax might be due.

Comment: I think it's New York, which would explain why NY showed up on her W-2.

Comment: @DStanley: I don't think that's true. I believe work income is generally considered to be sourced where the work is performed, not where the company is located.

Comment: The work is performed in france.... Which likely isn't an option in the payroll system.